# Easiest way to solve $y''+y=\frac{1}{\cos x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know how to solve it using Lagrange method of variation of constants, but is there easier way?

Comment: This can't really be answered because "easy" is subjective. Can you say more about how it should easier? Fewer steps when written on paper? Or are you just interested in alternate methods?

Comment: I mean way with fewer steps :)

Comment: Please show us the number of steps you do.

Comment: I don't think that it will answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to
$$
y''+y=0,\quad y(0)=0,\quad y'(0)=1
$$
is
$$
y(x)=\sin x
$$
Therefore, a particular solution to the problem we study is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
y(x)&=\int_0^x \sin(x-t)\sec(t)\,dt\\
&=\int_0^x \sin x-\cos x\tan t \,dt\\
&=x\sin x+\cos x\times\ln(\cos x).
\end{aligned}
$$
The solution to the homogeneous equation is trivial, so the general solution is
$$
y(x)=A\cos x+(B+x)\sin x+\cos x\times\ln(\cos x),
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants. I leave it to you to think of what happens when $\cos x\leq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the differential equation $$y''+a^2y=\sec ax$$

The auxiliary equation is $m^2+a^2=0$ which gives $m=\pm ia$

Hence $$CF=c_1\cos ax+c_2\sin ax$$

$$PI=\frac{1}{D^2+a^2}\sec ax=\frac{1}{(D-ia)(D+ia)}\sec ax\\
=\frac{1}{2ia}(\frac{1}{D-ia}-\frac{1}{D+ia})\sec ax$$

Now, $$\frac{1}{D-ia}\sec ax=e^{iax}\int e^{-iax}\sec ax \mathrm dx\\
=e^{iax}\int\frac{\cos ax-i\sin ax}{\cos ax}\mathrm dx=e^{iax}(x+\frac{i}{a}\log\cos ax)$$

Replacing $i$ by $-i$ we have, $$\frac{1}{D+ia}\sec ax=e^{-iax}(x-\frac{i}{a}\log\cos ax)$$

Now Using these and simplifying we have $$PI=\frac{1}{a^2}(ax\sin ax+\cos ax\cdot\log\cos ax)$$

Hence the general Solution is:

$$y=c_1\cos ax+c_2\sin ax+\frac{1}{a^2}(ax\sin ax+\cos ax\cdot\log\cos ax)$$

Put $a=1$ in this you will get your answer in very few steps.

Comment: Well, that is short. Too short for my taste, since it says nothing about how you achieve the general solution...

Comment: @mickep if you want, How it comes? I am going to edit my solution. Just wait

Comment: Well, apparently OP was happy with this solution, so why should I bother? :)

Comment: Nice! I was actually going in this direction first, but I got stuck on the integral...

Comment: @mickep when i answered first I just given the answer in a joking mood, because of title "in few steps" ;-), your comment realises me that it's not good so a decided to edit the complete answer.