# How could I solve the equation $y''+y= \frac{1}{\sin(t)}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How could I solve the differential equation $y''+y= \frac{1}{\sin(t)}$?

A short moment, I thought I could use the equation $y''+y= \sin(t)$. I think I have to find the general solution (trivial), but what about the particular solution?

Any idea?

Comment: [Method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients)? [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)?

Comment: What are you trying to solve for? y or t?

Comment: @Mattos Unfortunately, the LT of $\csc(t)$ does not exist ... so that's out.

Comment: You could also use the inverse operator method. I don't know why it's not as popular as the other methods.

Comment: Also, you could use [this method](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1396185/97236).

Comment: @Dr.MV Ah, I was looking at the $y'' + y = \sin(t)$ equation. My bad.

Comment: @mattos No worry.  I've made many careless errors that are far worse.  Be well.  ;-)  Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any solution to a differential equation of the kind $$y''+py'+qy=r$$ can be written as $$y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2+\overline{y}$$ where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two linearly independent solutions of the homogenous equation $$y''+py'+qy=0$$ and $\overline{y}$ is a particular solution of the original differential equation.

Now here, your homogenous equation is $$y''+y=0$$ Clearly $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ are two solutions. Both are linearly independent. Now to find the partcular solution, use the [Method of Variation of parameters](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/variation/variation.html). Note that the wronskian($W$) of $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ is $-1$.

Thus, $\overline{y}=u_1y_1+u_2y_2$ where $$u_1=-\int \dfrac {y_2r}{W}\mathrm dt=-\int \dfrac {\cos t\cdot \dfrac {1}{\sin t}}{-1} \mathrm dt=\ln \sin t$$ and $$u_2=\int \dfrac {y_1r}{W}\mathrm dt=\int \dfrac {\sin t\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sin t}}{-1}\mathrm dt=-t$$

Therefore, $\overline{y}=\ln\sin t \cdot \sin t+(-t)\cdot \cos t$.

Thus the general solution is $$y=c_1\sin t+c_2\cos t+\ln\sin t \times \sin t+(-t)\times \cos t$$.

Comment: I'm going to suggest not using $\times$ when you do not have to as it can be confusing, consider using $\cdot$ (\cdot) instead. You should also not use quotation marks for second derivatives.

Comment: Hmm.. will edit it. Thank @CameronWilliams.